# How Do I left factor and eliminate left recursion?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, ll-grammar, left-recursion

My Production rules are as follows:

```
S → id = Exp
S → id (Arglist)
Arglist → Arglist , Exp
Arglist → Exp
Exp → id (Arglist)
Exp → id
```

This is my first attempt:

```
S -> id S'
S' -> ϵ | = EXP | (Arglist)
Arglist -> Arglist'
Arglist' -> ϵ | ,Exp Arglist'
Exp -> id Exp'
Exp' -> ϵ | (Arglist)
```

My problem is with the Arglist production rule, I am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change `Arglist` to being right-recursive, which will recognise the same language (with a slightly different parse tree):

```
Arglist → Exp , Arglist
Arglist → Exp
```

Then left-factor:

```
Arglist → Exp Arglist'
Arglist' → ε | , Exp Arglist'
```